# The 8-Puzzle game. How to check and change directory key values which represents a tile of game board

Tags: python

This is a game of the Eight Puzzle (3x3). I have to move the empty space in the puzzle to the left (if possible). I can't figure out how to check or change values of keys in the directory which get_empty() returns.

```
DEFAULT_BOARD = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 0]]
'''
A default board if another board is not specified in the constructor
'''

def get_empty(board):
    '''
    Finds the position of the empty space in the board
    :return: a dictionary eith the row and col of the empty space
    '''
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if board[i][j] == 0:
                **return {"row": i, "col": j}**

def __init__(self, the_board = DEFAULT_BOARD):
    '''
    Makes a new node from an initial board
    :param the_board: the initial board
    '''
    if EightGameNode.legal_board(the_board):
        # if the board is legal go on
        self.board = the_board
    else:
        # otherwise use the default board
        self.board = EightGameNode.DEFAULT_BOARD
    self.empty = EightGameNode.get_empty(self.board)
    # set the empty space of the board

def move_left(self):
    '''
    Moving the space to left
    :return: a new board position or None if not possible
    '''
    if self.empty == 
    #If the "col" key value is 0 the empty space can't move to the left
        return None
    else:
    #Increase the col value by +1
        self.empty
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I really understand what you are asking. You should not just update the `self.empty` dict, but instead move the actual values on the board and then use your function to re-calculate `self.empty`

```
def move_left(self):
    r, c = self.empty["row"], self.empty["col"]
    # assuming with "move left" you mean to move the "hole" left
    if c > 0:
        self.board[r][c] = self.board[r][c-1] # move piece to the right into the "hole"
        self.board[r][c-1] = 0 # new position of the empty cell
    self.empty = EightGameNode.get_empty(self.board)
```

This will ensure consistency between `self.board` and `self.empty` and make the code a bit shorter and less prone for copy-paste errors between the different `move` methods. Of course, you could also update `self.empty` directly, which would be faster than scanning the whole board again, but if this is actually a game played by a human (and not e.g. using millions of playouts to train an AI or similar) this will not matter at all.

If speed really *is* important, and this poses too much of a slow-down, you can update the `empty` position like this, within the `if`, and remove the call to `get_empty` below:

```
        self.empty["col"] -= 1 # update self.empty to new "hole" position
```

Comment: It is for an AI, not for human players. Will this solution not work in this case?

Comment: It will still work, but as I said, it mill be a little slower. Basically you'd scan all the fields of the board again to find the empty cell when you actually already know where it will be after the move.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
def move_left(self):
    '''
    Moving the space to left
    :return: a new board position or None if not possible
    '''
    if self.empty["col"] == 0:
        return None
    else:
        self.empty["col"] = self.empty["col"] - 1
```

Comment: This does not properly update the board, though. It just lets `self.empty` point to a cell that is _not_ the empty cell.

Comment: Please read `I can't figure out how to check or change values of keys in the directory which get_empty() returns`... here OP mentioned how to change the value of `keys` returned by `get_empty()`

Comment: You are right, new value is not `empty`. But my guess is that logic might be handled in some other function